# Request For Member UiTextField In Something Not a Struct

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I keep getting this error when trying to access the textfield value of my view:

```
error: request for member 'inputAnswer' in something not a structure or union
```

The UITextField is declared as follows:

```
@interface TextInputQuestionViewController : UIViewController {
    Question *question;
    IBOutlet UILabel *questionTitle;
    IBOutlet UILabel *inputLabel;
    IBOutlet UITextField *inputAnswer;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *questionTitle;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *inputLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Question *question;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *inputAnswer;
```

I am trying to access the textfield as follows (as it is nested):

```
NSLog(@"%@", currQ.question.inputAnswer.text);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Update: @sergio you are right, I did mean that but it still throws this error. I'm sure its pointing at the right place too...

```
//pushes new view onto navigation controller stack
-(void) switchViews:(id)sender{ 
    if(currQNum < [questionArray count] - 1){
        if(currQNum > 0){
            Answer* ans = currQ.question.answer;
            ans.questionId = currQ.question.qId;
            ans.entryId = @"1";//temporary;
            //if else for different input types
            NSString* qt = currQ.question.qType;
            if([qt isEqualToString:@"Slider"]){
                ans.answer = currQ.sliderLabel.text;
            }else if([qt isEqualToString:@"Option"]){               

            }else if([qt isEqualToString:@"TextInput"]){
                NSLog(@"%@", currQ.inputAnswer.text); //PROBLEM
                //ans.answer = currQ.inputAnswer.text;
            }else if([qt isEqualToString:@"ImagePicker"]){

            }else{

            }                       
            [answerArray addObject: ans];
            [ans release];
        }
        [self startQuestion:currQNum isLast:FALSE];     
        currQNum++;
    }else{
        Answer* ans = currQ.question.answer;
        ans.questionId = currQ.question.qId;
        ans.answer = currQ.sliderLabel.text;
        ans.entryId = @"1";//temporary;
        [answerArray addObject: ans];
        [ans release];
        //store data temporarily - section finished     
        [self startQuestion:currQNum isLast:TRUE];              
        currQNum++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the exact error. It looks like you've paraphrased it in the title.

Comment: I don't know what the error is, but it seems like a reasonable guess that your `Question` class doesn't have a data member called `inputAnswer`.

Comment: you are right, it is a member of TextInputViewController, my silly mistake. I have changed it now though and it still throws this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly you meant:

```
NSLog(@"%@", currQ.inputAnswer.text);
```

The error message:

> error: request for member 'inputAnswer' in something not a structure or union

means that the compiler cannot recognize `currQ` as a structure or a union (or an Objective-C object).

Comment: inputAnswer is a property of TextInputQuestionViewController. currQ references a particular instance of TextinputQuestionViewController...using currQ.question poses no problems but currQ.inputAnswer does...

Comment: Then, I guess that you did not `import` `TextInputQuestionViewController` header file where you execute the NSLog...

Comment: that's isn;t the issue. I have imported it into the class's header file. I can reference the TextInputViewController's question property..just not the inputAnswer...

Comment: are you referencing `currQ.question` and `currQ.inputAnswer` at the same point? possibly without seeing more code, it will be difficult to understand what is happening...

Comment: strange thing: `ans.answer = currQ.sliderLabel.text;`: `sliderLabel` is no property of `TextInputQuestionViewController` and this should not compile. Could you check the definition of `currQ` from the header file? Does the `sliderLabel` suggest anything to you? in which class is it defined? some older version of `TextInputQuestionViewController`?

Comment: I know it isn't, thats because I am creating a different viewcontroller in that if statement. In another function I use a variable to determine what type of viewcontroller to create (similar to the if else structure here)..if the qType = @"TextInput" I create a TextInputViewController..I NSLog(@"%@", currQ) and it says its a TextInputQuestionViewController, but I just cannot access it's inputAnswer property...

Comment: Could you explain that better? You have some kind of base class for your questions and then you instantiate one concrete class and that is currQ? what is exactly `currQ` declaration?